# Не работает .attr

Tags: jquery

```
<button class ="btn btn-default pull-right" id="save"  onclick="echoq();">Сохранить</button>

<div id="resultVK" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable col-md-6 pull-right" style="display:none;">
    <button  class="close" id="close" onclick="close();">×</button>
        Текст
</div>
```

Функции:

```
function echoq(){
  $( "#resultVK" ).removeAttr( "style" );
}
function close(){
  $( "#resultVK" ).attr("style","display:none");
}
```

Т.е. при нажатии сохранить - показать блок. При нажатии х - скрыть.
Но почему-то скрытие не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Почему не работает?**
Функция `close` не работает, поскольку у js есть нативный метод `close` и при его вызове вызывается не ваша функция, а нативная.

**Решение лучше**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
  $('#resultVK').show();
});

$(document).on('click', '#close', function() {
  $('#resultVK').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class ="btn btn-default pull-right" id="save">Сохранить</button>

<div id="resultVK" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable col-md-6 pull-right" style="display:none;">
    <button  class="close" id="close">×</button>
        Текст
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

зачем удалять style? меняйте только display:

```
$( "#resultVK" ).css("display","none");// hidden
$( "#resultVK" ).css("display","");// show
```

Answer (score 0):

У `window` есть функция [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/close). Переопределить её, надо полагать, нельзя. Поэтому стоит изменить имя функции. Например, на `closeResult`.

Использование inline-JS (`onclick=""`) не приветствуется обществом уже немало лет. Возникшая проблема с именем функции - ещё один камень в огород inline_JS.
И, конечно, для работы со стилями лучше использовать `.css()`.